# How do you weight cases in a BRFSS dataset opened in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I'm a Penn State student working on a class project in SPSS where I'm trying to weight cases in the 2019 BRFSS dataset that I have uploaded to the program. Most of the class is using the NHANES dataset, and they weight samples by 2-year interview weight. My professor and I are having a very difficult time trying to figure out which sample weighting to use for the BRFSS dataset. There are instructions for how to do this in SAS (use the _LLCPWT for weighting cases), but this does not work in SPSS. Is anyone aware of how to turn on sample weighting in the 2019 BRFSS dataset in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`WEIGHT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_weight.html) command to weight cases. The weights should be in a variable in your dataset.

If the variable containing the sample weights is called _LLCPWT, then you can activate weighting by running the following command in a Syntax window:

```
weight by _LLCPWT.
```

When activated, the bottom right corner of your Data Editor windows will indicate 'Weight On`.